# pasting excel chart in word changes the chart's font

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have charts in excel with the Arial font for the title and all axes.

When I copy & paste the charts/graphs into a word document, the font changes to Times New Roman.

Is there a way to set word up so this doesn't happen, it is a time waster to change all charts' fonts one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution that worked for me. It basically says to check the font of the chart. In my case it said *Calibri (body)*. The "body" part is what is causing the font change.

changing the font to a normal Calibri (or whichever font you want) stops the font from changing when copying charts from MS Excel to MS Word